# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _ElementStringResult

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the code as below but end up return an error which is uncommon and can't find any information to understand what is wrong.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _ElementStringResult

My code is as below:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

StockData = ['KTC','DANCO','PTRANS']
Stocklen = len(StockData)

df_Year = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','Year'])
df_ROE = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','ROE'])

for x in range (len(StockData)):
    print "###############  "
    print StockData [x]
    print "###############"

    page_wsj2 = requests.get('http://abc/'+StockData[x]+'/financials/quartre/income-statement')
    wsj2 = html.fromstring(page_wsj2.content)

     page_wsj4 = requests.get('http://abc/'+StockData[x]+'/financials/quartre/balance-sheet')
     wsj4 = html.fromstring(page_wsj4.content)

    Year = 2016
    df_Year.loc[len(df_Year)] = [StockData[x],Year]

    NI4Q = wsj2.xpath('//tr[.="Net Income"]/following-sibling::td/text()')
    NI4Q = [x.replace(",", "") for x in NI4Q]
    NI4Q = ['-' + y.strip('()') if '(' in y else y for y in NI4Q]
    print NI4Q
    NI = float(NI4Q[0])+float(NI4Q[1])+float(NI4Q[2])+float(NI4Q[3])
    print NI
    Equity = wsj4.xpath('//td[.="Total Equity"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
    #NI = NI.replace(',','') #float object has no attribute 'replace'
     Equity = Equity.replace(',','')
     print NI
     print Equity

      Equity = float(Equity)
      wsj_calROE = (NI/Equity)*100
      ROE = wsj_calROE
      print "ROE"
      print ROE
      df_ROE.loc[len(df_ROE)] = [StockData[x],"%.2f"%ROE]
```

From the output, the calculation part of ROE is correct until the line of `df_ROE.loc[len(df_ROE)] = [StockData[x],"%.2f"%ROE]`. It is rather weird. ROE is float now. What format I should do let it work correctly?

```
###############  
KTC
###############
['-710.0', '716.0', '913.0', '246.0', '1041.0', ' ', ' ']
1165.0
1165.0
93714.0
wow
1165.0
ROE
1.24314403398
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/tyua/marketdata.py", line 84, in <module>    df_ROE.loc[len(df_ROE)] = [StockData[x],ROE]TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _ElementStringResult
```

Comment: Looks like you redefine `x` during the loop. Search your code for `x` and you'll see where it is happening.

Comment: @Shadow the for loop run correctly as the output only stop after I print ROE values. Let me check if I paste the code wrongly

Comment: The error happening only after you print ROE makes sense when you consider where `x` is redefined, and then where it is used after redefinition. I don't think it's a problem with your pasted code...

Comment: Not sure I get you correctly. I change `NI4Q = [x.replace(",", "") for x in NI4Q]` to `NI4Q = [a.replace(",", "") for a in NI4Q]` but return the same error

Comment: Thanks, I got it now